# Как запустить один фрагмент из другого

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Есть активность, которая имеет 2 фрагмента, при запуске приложения запускается первый фрагмент, на котором есть кнопка, после нажатия на кнопку должен запускаться второй фрагмент, как это реализовать?

Comment: это чисто случайно не домашнее задание технопарка mail.ru, хмм?)

Comment: @nick, нет_____

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, через `fragmentManager`:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2, "TAG") 
    .commit();
```

Пример простейший, совсем учебный. Но если погуглите про `FragmentManager`, то легко разберетесь и с более сложными вариантами его использования.

```
fragment_container//контейнер, в котором был старый фрагмент и теперь будет новый
fragment2// экземпляр нового фрагмента (его создаете сами, например через new)
```

Comment: Премного благодарен!