# Инициализировать кнопки с разных fragment, которые будут менять один фрагмент на другой

Tags: android, android-fragment, kotlin

Мне нужно реализовать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки фрагмент MainFragment менялся на SinFrag и наоборот, причем эта кнопка индивидуальна для каждого фрагмента. reb_fr_sin вызывает главное меню с цифрами а reb_fr_main - меню с синусами. Эти кнопки вызывают функцию frChange(). Проблема в том, что если я по умолчанию вызываю в поле для фрагмента фрагмент с цифрами, то кнопка со второго фрагмента не инициализируется. Ошибку приложил

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        main()
    }

    private fun main() {
        val frag1 = MainFragment()
        val frag2 = SinFrag()

        reb_fr_main.setOnClickListener {frChange(frag2)}
        reb_fr_sin.setOnClickListener {frChange(frag1)}

    }

    private fun frChange(fragment: Fragment) {
            val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
            val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmento, fragment)
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.mycalk.MainActivity.main(MainActivity.kt:25)
    at com.example.mycalk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

[image: интерфейс]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1107941/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Такой конструкцией можно добиться смены фрагментов друг из друга

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    main()
}

private fun main() {
    reb_fr_main.setOnClickListener {

        Log.d("sf", "fergsrtgsbvsfvgbgmainnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn")
        var fragmentManager = fragmentManager
        fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
            ?.replace(R.id.fragment_container, SinFrag(), "TAG1")
            ?.commit();
    }
}
```

}